# Only output XML elements that are set when serializing

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I have the following XML:

```
<Line id="6">
  <item type="product" />
  <warehouse />
  <quantity type="ordered" />
  <comment type="di">Payment by credit card already received</comment>
</Line>
```

Is there a way to not output the elements that aren't set when serializing an object in .NET (2010 with C#)? In my case, the `item type`, the `warehouse`, the `quantity` so that I end up with the following instead when serialized:

```
<Line id="6">
  <comment type="di">Payment by credit card already received</comment>
</Line>
```

I can't see any properties in the XmlElement or XmlAttribute that would let me achieve this.

Is XSD required? If it is, how would I go about it?

Comment: in the example above, though, `item` and `quantity` *do* have values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For simple cases, you can usually use `[DefaultValue]` to get it to ignore elements. For more complex cases, then for any **member** `Foo` (property / field) you can add:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeFoo() {
    // TODO: return true to serialize, false to ignore
}
[XmlElement("someName");
public string Foo {get;set;}
```

This is a name-based convention supported by a number of frameworks and serializers.

For example, this writes just `A` and `D`:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class MyData {
    public string A { get; set; }
    [DefaultValue("b")]
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeC() => C != "c";

    public string D { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeD() => D != "asdas";

}
class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var obj = new MyData {
            A = "a", B = "b", C = "c", D = "d"
        };
        new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType())
            .Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
    }
}
```

`B` is omitted because of `[DefaultValue]`; `C` is omitted because of the `ShouldSerializeC` returning `false`.

Comment: "DefaultValue" did the trick and also great to see the other technique with the properties. Many thanks.